# create custom sidecar and inject in istio service mesh

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, servicemesh

I am new to the world of sidecar and istio. Have been reading about this for around a week. But still can't find an perfect answer.

First of all, is it possible to inject a custom sidecar using istio. Functionality that i want to achieve is, in request header i will receive 2 tokens(JWT). One for issuer (nonce), and other for sender (pop). I need to verify whether both these tokens are correct and if correct, i can allow them access to my microservice or else reject straight away.

So in order to achieve this functionality, i have created a sidecar, and now i want to deploy it using istio. But i can't find a way, to do it.

What i am able to achieve is the automatic sidecar injection that happens as soon as i install my containers. But now where i am struct is, i want custom sidecar to be injected using istio.

Let me know if anyone can give me a direction in what i am trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Where you able to do this properly? Also wanted to know how you built the sidecar? did you create the new side car as same as `istio-proxy ` side car or built it in a different language like Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in istio with a custom sidecar injection template.

For example to overwrite the default sidecar `istio-proxy`, just create an overlay for the template in the `IstioOperator`:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio
spec:
  values:
    sidecarInjectorWebhook:
      templates:
        custom: |
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: istio-proxy
              env:
              - name: GREETING
                value: hello-world
```

By that the proxy would get the extra `GREETING` environment variable. You can also inject a second/different custom sidecar. First add it in the `IstioOperator` manifest:

```yaml
[...]
  values:
    sidecarInjectorWebhook:
      templates:
        custom: |
          spec:
            containers:
            - name: my-custom-container
              image: my-custom-image
```

Now you can control which sidecar will be injected by annotation the pod with the `inject.istio.io/templates` annotation.

To replace the default `istio-proxy` sidecar set it like  `inject.istio.io/templates=custom`.

To inject it as a secondary sidecar set it like `inject.istio.io/templates=sidecar,custom`, where `sidecar` would be the default istio sidecar.

You can check the `istio-sidecar-injector` configmap in the `istio-system` namespace to inspect the default config and also to verify your changes.

More on that see [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#custom-templates-experimental)

Note that the feature is currently still experimental.

**Edit**

Here is an example deployment that would utilize a second sidecar. Note the `annotation` in the pod template:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
      annotations: 
        inject.istio.io/templates: sidecar,custom # for custom sidecar
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your input. But where are the annotations to be kept?. Can you show entire yaml file and corresponding commands. Even the doc dosent have much details.